# Fast modular addition of 2 (potentially large) files in java

Tags: java, performance, cryptography, nio

I am doing a cryptography experiment with One Time Pads.

I have two files OTP and TEXT (1K-10K) with bytes in them.  OTP is large (>1GB).  I want to create a third file CYPHERTEXT (same size as TEXT) by performing modular addition of TEXT with OTP using an offset into OTP.  I coded this by hand using java.io, and it works, but isn't very snappy, even with buffered IO (streams or writers).

I was looking for a way to add one of underlying byte buffers together with the other one using NIO but could not find a (built-in) way to do that, or to filter the contents of TEXT using the data from OTP except by hand.  Is there any way to do something like this without reinventing the wheel?  I thought I could use a selector.  Ideally I'd like to be able to handle files larger than 2GB in size for both the OTP and the TEXT which is why I was looking at NIO.

```
private static void createOTP() {
...
System.out.print("Generating " + filename + " ");
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, MB);
for(long currentSize =0; currentSize < OTPSize; currentSize += baSize){
   new SecureRandom().nextBytes(ba);
   bos.write(ba);
   if(currentSize % (MB * 20L * (long)sizeInGB)==0){
      System.out.print(".");
   }
}
long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
System.out.println(" OTP generation elapsed Time is " + (elapsedTime / 1000000.0) + " msec");
fos.close();
bos.close();
...
}

private static void symetricEncryptionDecryption(boolean encrypt) { 
...
outtext=new File(intext.getParentFile(), direction + ".OTP");
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outtext), MB);
byte[] plaindata = new byte[(int)intext.length()];
DataInputStream dataIs = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(intext));
dataIs.readFully(plaindata);
dataIs.close();
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(plaindata);
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(otpFile))); 
in.skip(offset);
while(bb.hasRemaining()){
    bos.write( bb.get() + (encrypt? in.readByte() : -in.readByte()) );
}
bos.close();
in.close();
System.out.println("Offset: " + offset);
}
```

So is there a far slicker way to do this:

```
while(bb.hasRemaining()){
    bos.write( bb.get() + (encrypt? in.readByte() : -in.readByte()) );
}
```

Or to generate the OTP for that matter.

Comment: I suggest you clarify what you mean.  a 1 GB file is large so it is going to take time to process and read/write.  You haven't said which disk drive you have and this is likely to be critical to how fast you can do this, what you do in Java is lees likely to be important.  Stream can be any length so you can use Plain IO as well as NIO.  It's not clear what you are doing but if you read/process 8 bytes at a time e.g. a long, you are likely to be fast enough.

Comment: I added example code.  1 GB is a small OTP for these purposes.  So it would be nice to have the data I'm encrypting be of any size, including over the 2GB int limit.  This is all going to a normal 7200rpm IDE HDD, or maybe a USB 3.0 drive.

Comment: Where does the `int` limit apply?  BTW There is nothing preventing you reading the TEXT file progressively in the same way you are reading the OTP file progressively.  You should be able to read/write a 1 MB file in less than 0.1 seconds.

Comment: BTW If you use the `^` bitwise XOR, you can apply it to both encode and decode and you can apply it N bytes at a time e.g. 8 bytes at a time, instead of one byte at a time.

Comment: Generating the OTP is going to be expensive by intent.  You could generate much smaller file. i.e. only as large as you need and use a less expensive random generator.

Comment: BTW Your OTP file doesn't have to be private or generated.  You could use a publicly available image(s) of a decent size to form an OTP.

Comment: The int limit applies because the buffer can't be larger then the largest byte[] you can create which takes int as it's size argument.  A video DVD for instance can easily be larger than that size.  I can of course use arrays of arrays etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are trying to do but if you memory map the OTP file, giving you random access, and you read/process 8 bytes at a time i.e. `long` values you should eb able to write an encrypted 10K text file under 100 ms where most that time will be spend starting the JVM.

BTW: if you have access to the encrypted TEXT and OTP file you might decode the text without he offset i.e. you could work it out using brute force.

Comment: The scheme relies on the OTP never being reused and upon secure escrow of the keys.  The problem then becomes one merely of key distribution.  "If the key is truly random, and at least as long as the plaintext, and never reused in whole or in part, and kept completely secret, then the resulting ciphertext will be impossible to decrypt or break.[1][2]" <wikipedia>

Comment: @GGB667 That is what I thought.

Comment: By constantly transmitting noise only the person receiving the data who already had the OTP could know if a message was even being transmitted.  If the volume of noise is sufficient, and the noise to signal rate is sufficiently high an attacker would have to store ALL of the transmitted data if they subsequently came into possession of a key to find the messages that had been sent.  I only use the OTP when I'm actually sending a message.  If the noise is randomly delayed before transmission to frustrate timing analysis only capture of the OTP and recording of all the data will work.

Comment: @GGB667 Are you trying to make something impossible to break, more impossible?

Comment: It's not impossible to break. The attackers just have to get the one time pad. Then they can read anything ever sent. Unless they can't STORE everything you (and the 2 billion other things using this encryption scheme) have already sent. It would let the government target specific criminals or terrorists and the people they communicate with but not the entire world

Comment: @GGB667 If you have the OTP you can always decode the message, that is the point.  Adding noise just makes it a bit harder when it is already impossible without the OTP anyway. i.e. it will just make your life harder for no benefit.

Comment: Not a bit harder.  Impossible unless you already stored all previous traffic.  You can read future messages, but not past ones from before you started recording everything.  For example my upload bandwidth is 0.6 TB/dy.  No one, not even the NSA is going to want to record hundreds of TB of noise.

Comment: I don't see how making the task more onerous makes it harder to crack.  If you have the OTP you can decode the message, period and the NSA doesn't care how much data it needs to record.

Comment: An attacker can only decode NEW messages after the pad is captured.- unless everything is saved.  So if A communicates to B, and A became aware B's OTP was compromised it compartmentalizes the leak to only the information after the OTP was compromised.  A could also say to C using the same channel of data that "A is going to transmit to a new OTP to C starting at 1:12 PM and running till 1:15 PM.", from now on use that pad, let the Attacker have pad C, we'll send them false information from now on.  A could also talk using multiple OTPs with B, C, and D on the same channel.